# Unable to delete page in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am in sharepoint 2013 and when l try to delete a page l get the following message :

Cannot complete this action. This item cannot be deleted because an item in the "Discussions List" list is related to an item in the "Pages" list.

but l don't have anything linked to the discussion list so not sure why its throwing up that error

Comment: What kind of permission did you have?

Answer (score 2):

Empty your SharePoint site's recycle bin (_layouts/recyclebin.aspx) and the Admin recycle bin (/_layouts/AdminRecycleBin.aspx)and try .

http://www.ucdenver.edu/about/departments/WebServices/sharepoint/onlineTraining/Page/EditPage/Pages/Deleteapage.aspx